# Identifying a part behind front bumper cover

Tags: part-identification

I am trying to identify a certain part but after extensive googling still don't have an answer. So the part that I am looking at is located just behind the front bumper cover and above the engine under cover (Left) of a 2003 Toyota Camry. It is a black container of some kind. I have read the user manual from cover to cover but couldn't identify this part. Actually I found all the manuals describe only the parts located right under the bonnet while the one I'm after is a bit lower, closer to the wheel. I couldn't identify anything that is connected to it as it's hidden from sight. I realize that's a bit vague but any ideas?

[image]

Comment: take a picture of the component you would like to identify.  This will go a long way in helping narrow down what you're looking for.

Comment: @SteveRacer Yes I agree of course. The problem however is that I do not have access to the car right now and won't have for a couple more days so wanted to get some info meanwhile.

Comment: Is there tubing, ducting, or hoses attached to it?

Comment: My 2004 corolla had intake and battery over there. It could be a resonator, or a part of the intake system. Your best bet is to look for a shop manual for the car.

Comment: Just added the picture of the part. Hope that sheds some light.

Answer (score 1):

Black makes me think that it might be part of the air intake system. Could be the intercooler.

Since you don't have access to the car, could you describe it a bit more? What's connected? How big is it?

Comment: Is there anything that you see connected to it? I don't think I see anything. That's puzzling.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is visible from the exposed side as you can see. The top and the back are hidden and I couldn't get to them easily without trying to dismantle it.

Comment: How is it attached to the car?

Answer (score 0):

If one is windshield washer. I would assume the other one is engine coolant overflow bottle. One way to test that theory is to drive a good distance and let the engine cool. If the bottle is scalding hot then you will know.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however when I search for engine coolant bottle, it seems to appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

https://itstillruns.com/air-intake-resonator-do-12156112.html  looks like a air intake resenator.